# How do I pass reference of the p tag when ever the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is how i have created the button

```
<button type="submit" id="likebtn" onclick="likedpost(this) " data-postid="<%=blog._id%>" data-author="<%=user.username%>">Like</button>
                
<span ><p id="likescounter"><%=blog.likes%> </p></span> // I want to pass the reference of this p (id) when clicked the above button
```

This is my liked post function-

```
function likedpost(el)
{
  var id = el.dataset.postid;
  var author = el.dataset.author;
  console.log("id form likedpost function =" +id+"and author of this post is="+author);
  console.log('post liked');
  var request = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "api/index/like",
  data: {id: id, author:author},
  async:false,
  dataType:"html",
  success: function(data){
    findingnumberoflikes(data);
    console.log("action performed successfully")
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log("error occured");
  }

  });
}

function findingnumberoflikes(data)
{
  console.log("the data returned is "+ data);
  $(#likescounter).html(data); // here I can not select the likescounter id
  console.log("likes counter updated");
}
```

Basically, I want to select the respective p with jquery's $ selector and update its data but it is giving me `private identifiers are not allowed outside class bodies` error.
How can I do that. Thank you!

There is a list of above buttons and p tag are for every blog post in the databse. Sorry! earlier I couldn't frame my question better.

Comment: What does `likedpost` do? Can you add that code to your question because that seems to be problem.

Comment: I have added the code. can you please take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we can do this with sibling selector etc.. I suggest you to arrange this differently for example,

```
<span ><p id="likescounter"><%=blog.likes%> </p></span>
```

in this  line, change `id="likescounter"` to something that would give likescounter+blogid

something that would replace like the following

```
<span ><p id="likescounter-<%=blog._id%>"><%=blog.likes%> </p></span>
```

you wanna get "id=likescounter-1" for blog id 1, id="likescounter-2" for blog id 2 etc...

so essentially the id will be unique for each with "likescounter-" and corresponding blogid combied with it.

then in the button click function, simply do this

```
function likedpost(el){
    var id = el.dataset.postid;

    // Here's the reference to the element 
    // with jquery syntax it would be 
    var likesCounter = $("#likescounter-"+id)

    // for vanilla js it would be
    var likesCounter = document.getElementById("likescounter-"+id)
    ...
}
```